# Eine Beratung ist eine Beratung ist eine Beratung

Tags: idiom

Leider kann ich keine Quelle angeben. Jedoch habe ich schon öfter diese Verdopplung von "ist ein(e)" gesehen. Was will man damit eigentlich sagen? Etwa "Eine Beratung ist eine Beratung und nichts anderes"? Woher kommt die Ausdrucksweise?

('Beratung' habe ich jetzt einfach mal angenommen - vielleicht wird das aber auch nur mit bestimmten Wörtern in anderen Zusammenhängen gemacht?)

Comment: Im Arabischen würde man soetwas توكيد  = Beteuerung oder Bekräftigung nennen.

Comment: Ich kenne diese Ausdrucksweise in erster line als ein Zitat aus Star Trek "Ein Vertrag ist ein Vertrag ist ein Vertrag" - Ferrengi.

Comment: @lokimidgard Anscheinend lesen die Ferengi auch Gertrude Stein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die Formulierung, dass ein Ding ein Ding und ein Ding ist, ist ein Zitat aus dem (englischen) Gedicht von *Gertrude Stein* ["Sacred Emily"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose)

> a rose is a rose is a rose

und bedeutet so viel wie "Die Dinge sind so, wie sie eben sind".

Seinen Ursprung hat diese Aussage im "Satz der Identität", ein Begriff aus der Logik, der auf Aristoteles zurückgeht und soviel sagt wie "ein Ding ist ein Ding" (ach...).

Comment: Zugleich unterstreicht der Satz, dass man beim zweiten Rose schon eine andere Rose denkt, als beim ersten Auftritt, und die dritte Rose lässt einen nochmal tiefer reflektieren und wieder neue Rosenaspekte ans Tageslicht befördern, womit sich der Satz dementiert zu "Eine Rose ist keine Rose ist niemals eine Rose". :)